# how can I use different CSVs for my JMeter script on different instance

Tags: jmeter

We have 20 worker on AWS and I want to parameterized CSV file name for each instance Please help

I have  divided my  CSV in to number of Load generator hosts

```
$ wc -l "youroriginalcsv.csv" /* this will return number of total rows in csv*/
$ split -l "count of above query"/"number of hosts" "youroriginalcsv.csv" /* this will split CSV with file name as xaa, xab ... */
```

Transfer each unique CSV to all available hosts

```
$ scp xaa host1_user@host1_ip:/csvpath/csvfile.csv
$ scp xab host2_user@host2_ip:/csvpath/csvfile.csv
```

```
$ scp xaz hostN_user@hostN_ip:/csvpath/csvfile.csv
```

Now I want to use specific file name for specific host

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "specific file name for specific host"? Your CSV files are all named  `csvfile.csv` so it's sufficient to specify `/csvpath/csvfile.csv` in the [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) and each JMeter slave will pick up its own file containing partial data from the "big" CSV file.

If you want to use different names for CSV files depending on the machine IP address or DNS hostname - go for combination of [If Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) with [__machineName()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineName) or [__machineIP()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineIP) function

Also if you don't want the same data to be re-used by different JMeter slaves you can consider using [Redis Data Set Config](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/Using-Redis-Dataset-JMeter-Plugin) or [HTTP Simple Table Server](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HttpSimpleTableServer/), this way you won't have to "split" and "copy" CSV files and will be able to centrally manage your test data from a single location

Comment: Thank you Dmitri T, I want to use different names for CSV files depending on the machine IP address